# HTML no Spring Boot não encontra arquivos

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estou tentando carregar um arquivo de audio em um html, dessa forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando abro o html no navegador ele carrega normalmente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem quando faço o mesmo inicializando a aplicação spring, o html não carrega o arquivo sendo que é o mesmo arquivo (wtf).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu nao entendo é o que o src da tag audio tem a ver com o spring boot.

OBS: Estou usando apenas thymeleaf e spring-web como dependencias no POM.

Comment: Olá voce tem que passar xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> no arquivo html e baixar a dependencia do thymeleaf no arquivo pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguns passos devem ser seguidos para ter o thymeleaf em um projeto de spring boot.

### Dependências

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
 <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

### Cabeçalho do html

Se não for usar um layout de referência, tente usar esse cabeçalho de html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Para entender como funciona os layouts (quando você cria uma base, pode utilizá-lo em outras páginas):
[veja aqui](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout)

### Referência aos recursos

Para se referenciar a um recurso estático (imagens, arquivos css, etc) utilize sempre a sintaxe de `@{'/pasta_do_recurso/arquivo.extensao'}`

Exemplo:
`@{'/css/estilo.css'}` para o caso de um arquivo localizado em `src/main/resources/static/css/estilo.css`

Exemplo mais completo abaixo. Lembrando que sempre utilize o prefixo antes da tag padrão do html... esse prefixo que foi referenciado no início do html para o thymeleaf, no caso o `th`:
`<img th:src="@{/img/minha-logo.png}">`

Faça dessa maneira colocando seu arquivo mp3 em uma pasta dentro de uma pasta dentro de static, por exemplo, e referenciando ela de acordo com o nome dessa pasta. É uma prática comum.

Acredito que ficaria o seguinte para uma pasta `/static/audios` contendo o arquivo `mp3`:

```html
<audio th:src="@{/audios/musica.mp3}" controls></audio>
```